# generate smooth curve in clip-path: polygon

Tags: css, clip-path

I have a div element where I want to add inside curve using clip path: polygon css...

I have achieved the basic shape but unable to smooth out the curve.

[image]

HTML:

```
<div id="clip_element">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#clip_element {
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #c0c0c0, #adadad, #9a9a9a, #888888, #767676);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #c0c0c0, #adadad, #9a9a9a, #888888, #767676);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #c0c0c0, #adadad, #9a9a9a, #888888, #767676);  
  -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
  -moz-border-radius: 15px;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 0%,100% 0%,100% 70%,90% 80%,80% 90%,70% 100%,0% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0%,100% 0%,100% 70%,90% 80%,80% 90%,70% 100%,0% 100%);
  }
```

How to make the curve smooth with the clip-path:polygon?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have this by using pseudo element `:after`. Here is the answer by using this. Hope it helps.

```css
#clip_element {
width:200px;
height:75px;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #c0c0c0, #adadad, #9a9a9a, #888888, #767676);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #c0c0c0, #adadad, #9a9a9a, #888888, #767676);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #c0c0c0, #adadad, #9a9a9a, #888888, #767676);  
  -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
  -moz-border-radius: 15px;
  position:relative;  
  }
  div#clip_element:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    background: #fff;
    right: -10px;
    bottom: -30px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="clip_element">
</div>
```

Comment: @KumarAbhinav but you don't have transparency like with clip path

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can use svg clip path or converted svg to css clip path. So, the polygon taken in svg format.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 200.1 100.1" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
    .smooth_polygon{fill:#ababab;}
</style>
<path class="smooth_polygon" d="M200.1,15.7v40.9c-13.8-4.5-29.5-3-42.7,5.6c-13.4,8.8-21.1,23-22.2,37.9H15.6C7,100.1,0,93.1,0,84.5V15.6  C0,7,7,0,15.6,0h168.9C193.1,0.1,200.1,7.1,200.1,15.7z"/>
</svg>
```

After svg created and export you can directly use path tag d attribute values in our css style with "clip-path" property and value path("d attribute values"). Example given below,

```css
.smooth_curve_box
{
  width:210.1px;
  height: 100.1px;
  clip-path: path("M200.1,15.7v40.9c-13.8-4.5-29.5-3-42.7,5.6c-13.4,8.8-21.1,23-22.2,37.9H15.6C7,100.1,0,93.1,0,84.5V15.6  C0,7,7,0,15.6,0h168.9C193.1,0.1,200.1,7.1,200.1,15.7z");
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #c0c0c0, #adadad, #9a9a9a, #888888, #767676);  
}
```

```html
<div class="smooth_curve_box">
</div>
```

But that clipped path is not responsive, it means svg what width and height has that width & height only clipped on the element.  Above example shown svg has 200.1px but element "smooth_curve_box" has 210.1px width.  So, only 200.1px width area only clipped remaining all are empty.

If we want clipped area responsively then we need to convert the svg path d attribute values from absolute path to relative path.

After converted you can get path d attribute values like  "**M1,0.157 v0.409 c-0.069,-0.045,-0.147,-0.03,-0.213,0.056 c-0.067,0.088,-0.105,0.23,-0.111,0.379 H0.078 C0.035,1,0,0.93,0,0.844 V0.156 C0,0.07,0.035,0,0.078,0 h0.844 C0.965,0.001,1,0.071,1,0.157**".

But you can't use directly into css.  So, we need add some code into our html example given below.

```css
.clip_svg
{
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.smooth_curve_box_2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100.1px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #c0c0c0, #adadad, #9a9a9a, #888888, #767676);
  clip-path: url(#clip-path-id);
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.smooth_curve_box_3 {
  width: 200.1px;
  height: 100.1px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #c0c0c0, #adadad, #9a9a9a, #888888, #767676);
  clip-path: url(#clip-path-id);
}
```

```html
<svg class="clip_svg">
  <clipPath id="clip-path-id" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox"><path d="M1,0.157 v0.409 c-0.069,-0.045,-0.147,-0.03,-0.213,0.056 c-0.067,0.088,-0.105,0.23,-0.111,0.379 H0.078 C0.035,1,0,0.93,0,0.844 V0.156 C0,0.07,0.035,0,0.078,0 h0.844 C0.965,0.001,1,0.071,1,0.157"></path></clipPath>
</svg>

<div class="smooth_curve_box_2"></div>
<div class="smooth_curve_box_3"></div>
```

Above examples, second element is looking good but first element isn't. What happen here?  Because the responsive clip path worked only aspect ratio based.

If we want responsive only on portion area, then we need another one svg path to css clip path converter [here](https://www.plantcss.com/).

Here example of converted svg path to css clip path with portion area ony responsive using above mentioned online svg path converter.

```css
.smooth_curve_box_4
{
  width:100%;
  height: 300px;
  clip-path: polygon(calc(100% - 0px) 15.7px, calc(100% - 0px) calc(100% - 43.5px), calc(100% - 0px) calc(100% - 43.5px), calc(100% - 4.1926px) calc(100% - 44.6689px), calc(100% - 8.4727999999999px) calc(100% - 45.4712px), calc(100% - 12.8142px) calc(100% - 45.9003px), calc(100% - 17.1904px) calc(100% - 45.9496px), calc(100% - 21.575px) calc(100% - 45.6125px), calc(100% - 25.9416px) calc(100% - 44.8824px), calc(100% - 30.2638px) calc(100% - 43.7527px), calc(100% - 34.5152px) calc(100% - 42.2168px), calc(100% - 38.6694px) calc(100% - 40.2681px), calc(100% - 42.7px) calc(100% - 37.9px), calc(100% - 42.7px) calc(100% - 37.9px), calc(100% - 46.5481px) calc(100% - 35.1027px), calc(100% - 50.0488px) calc(100% - 32.0096px), calc(100% - 53.1967px) calc(100% - 28.6489px), calc(100% - 55.9864px) calc(100% - 25.0488px), calc(100% - 58.4125px) calc(100% - 21.2375px), calc(100% - 60.4696px) calc(100% - 17.2432px), calc(100% - 62.1523px) calc(100% - 13.0941px), calc(100% - 63.4552px) calc(100% - 8.8184px), calc(100% - 64.3729px) calc(100% - 4.4443px), calc(100% - 64.9px) calc(100% - 1.4210854715202E-14px), 15.6px calc(100% - 0px), 15.6px calc(100% - 0px), 13.0734px calc(100% - 0.20459999999999px), 10.6752px calc(100% - 0.79679999999998px), 8.4378px calc(100% - 1.7442px), 6.3936px calc(100% - 3.0144px), 4.575px calc(100% - 4.575px), 3.0144px calc(100% - 6.3936px), 1.7442px calc(100% - 8.4378px), 0.7968px calc(100% - 10.6752px), 0.2046px calc(100% - 13.0734px), 2.5884498452564E-31px calc(100% - 15.6px), 0px 15.6px, 0px 15.6px, 0.2046px 13.0734px, 0.7968px 10.6752px, 1.7442px 8.4378px, 3.0144px 6.3936px, 4.575px 4.575px, 6.3936px 3.0144px, 8.4378px 1.7442px, 10.6752px 0.7968px, 13.0734px 0.2046px, 15.6px 2.5884498452564E-31px, calc(100% - 15.6px) 0px, calc(100% - 15.6px) 0px, calc(100% - 13.0734px) 0.2317px, calc(100% - 10.6752px) 0.8456px, calc(100% - 8.4378px) 1.8099px, calc(100% - 6.3936px) 3.0928px, calc(100% - 4.575px) 4.6625px, calc(100% - 3.0144px) 6.4872px, calc(100% - 1.7442px) 8.5351px, calc(100% - 0.79680000000002px) 10.7744px, calc(100% - 0.2046px) 13.1733px, calc(100% - 2.8421709430404E-14px) 15.7px); 
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #c0c0c0, #adadad, #9a9a9a, #888888, #767676);
}
```

```html
<div class="smooth_curve_box_4"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For this shape we can also use a svg `mask` – using **primitives `<rect>` and `<circle>`**.

As these primitives support **relative units** - we can create a fluid-width mask.

First, we need to create a `<svg>` with a responsive/fluid layout:
The svg won't squeeze/distort the rounded corners or circle on resize.

```css
body{
  background:#333;
  color:#fff;
}

*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

.resize{
  resize:both;
  overflow:auto;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width:50%;
  padding:1em;
}
```

```html
<p>Resize me</p>
<div class="resize">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%">
      <rect x="0" y="0" rx='20' ry='20' width="100%" height="100%" fill="white" />
      <circle cx="100%" cy="100%" r="50" transform="translate(-30 0)" />
      </svg>
</div>
```

Then we need to convert the elements to a [`<mask>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/mask) element:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%">
    <mask id="mask">
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="white" />
      <circle cx="100%" cy="100%" r="50" transform="translate(-30 0)" />
    </mask>
    <rect mask="url(#mask)" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" rx='20' ry='20' fill="white" />
  </svg>
```

Now we can convert this svg to a data-URI e.g using [Yoksel's converter](https://yoksel.github.io/url-encoder/).
Compared to polygon based css clip-paths we get a **pretty compact** css rule as we don't need to approximate a curves by a lot of polygon vertices.:

```
  mask: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='100%25' height='100%25'%3E%3Cmask id='mask' %3E%3Crect x='0' y='0' width='100%25' height='100%25' fill='white'/%3E%3Ccircle cx='100%25' cy='100%25' r='50' transform='translate(-30 0)' /%3E%3C/mask%3E%3Crect mask='url(%23mask)' x='0' y='0' width='100%25' height='100%25' rx='20' ry='20' fill='white'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
```

#### Example: svg mask as data-URI

```css
body {
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.resize {
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 1em;
}

svg {
  display: block;
}

.clip_element {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10em;
  min-height: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #c0c0c0, #adadad, #9a9a9a, #888888, #767676);
  -webkit-mask: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='100%25' height='100%25'%3E%3Cmask id='mask' %3E%3Crect x='0' y='0' width='100%25' height='100%25' fill='white'/%3E%3Ccircle cx='100%25' cy='100%25' r='50' transform='translate(-30 0)' /%3E%3C/mask%3E%3Crect mask='url(%23mask)' x='0' y='0' width='100%25' height='100%25' rx='20' ry='20' fill='white'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  -webkit-mask-size: 100%;
  mask-type: luminance;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.w200x150 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
}

.w500x100 {
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<p>Mask svg</p>
<div style="width:1000px">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%">
    <mask id="mask">
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="white" />
      <circle cx="100%" cy="100%" r="50" transform="translate(-30 0)" />
    </mask>
    <rect mask="url(#mask)" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" rx='20' ry='20' fill="white" />
  </svg>
</div>

<p>Mask applied by data-uri</p>

<div class="resize">
  <div class="clip_element">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="clip_element w200x150">
</div>

<div class="clip_element w500x100">
</div>
```